# Create Oracle DB user with expiration time

Tags: oracle

I would like to create an Oracle DB user and I would like to disable him in exactly 8 hours.
I don't care if a user just gets locked or if all of his roles are revoked, I just want
to prevent him from doing any activities on DB exactly 8 hours after his DB user was created.

Does Oracle provide such option out of the box ?

If not, I might go with the following solution:

- create a table where all newly created DB users are stored (with DB user creation time)
- create a trigger on Create user, so I save DB username and his creation time in my table
- create a function / job that checks my table every 5 minutes if there's any user older than 8 hours and it locks him

My proposed solution is very nasty so I really hope there's a better solution for my issue.

Comment: Your proposed solution won't end an existing user session; it will only prevent new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a [profile](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/CREATE-PROFILE.html?source=ad:nat:::rc_lamk190221p00018c0002:taboola_iaas_pt_b)

> which is a set of limits on database resources. If you assign the profile to a user, then that user cannot exceed these limits.

Especially check the following parameters:

- CONNECT_TIME: Specify the total elapsed time limit for a session, expressed in minutes
- PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME: Specify the number of days the same password can be used for authentication. If you also set a value for PASSWORD_GRACE_TIME, then the password expires if it is not changed within the grace period, and further connections are rejected. If you omit this clause, then the default is 180 days